# Creating a top navigation menu

Tags: android, kotlin

How to make a top navigation menu as per the screenshot?

I want the top links to be clickable and scrollable as there are more items in top navigation.

[image: navigation screenshot]

Comment: Best approach would be to research and show some effort yourself. In case you don't know, only code and/or error based problems are recommended on Stack Overflow. As for your answer, research on View pager and fragments ;)

Comment: check this out: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18aEfUFCUVZVIfDRYp1A1mQQXA6zYdrAX

Comment: You should use TabLayout with ViewPager Please refer below link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: Visit this https://github.com/SuavePirate/KotlinPuppies

Answer (score 1):

Implement your xml views like:

```
 - CoordinatorLayout
  - LinearLayout
  - Toolbar
  - TabLayout
  - View Pager
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarTheme"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="1.6dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#c3ffffff" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then in **activity/fragment** setup view pager with TabLayout, add fragment in view pager and prepare recycler view in ViewPager Fragment.

```
 private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;    
         @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
             initialiseViews();
            setUpTabLayout();

        }

         public void initialiseViews() {   
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(tab_layout);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        }
        private void setUpTabLayout() {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.add(new YourFragment1(), "Home");
            adapter.add(new YourFragment2(), "Trending");
            adapter.add(new YourFragment3(), "Friends");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.setPageMargin((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.view_pager_gap));
            viewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.background);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

            private ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            void add(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                fragmentList.add(fragment);
                titleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return fragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return titleList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return fragmentList.size();
            }

           @Override
           public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
               return POSITION_NONE;
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TabLayout and ViewPager for creating user interface like mentioned above.
Refer this :
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Also some of the open source github projects are there.

Example:
https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Answer (score 0):

As I see also nav button which usually operates `NavigationDrawer` on your screen, I assume you may need it in the future.

To achieve what you call ***"the best approach"*** you should at first describe at least what architecture you're using by showing some code etc.

Let's assume you'll go "common" way with holder `Activity` and few `Fragment`s aka pages. Then, basically, what you need is custom `Adapter` for `ViewPager`:

At first, you need right layout, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#464646"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:titleTextColor="#e1e1e1" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#606060"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_general" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then goes Kotlin part. Here i show code snippet which connects ViewPages and DrawerLayout functionalities:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private val pageTitles = arrayOf("TITLE_ONE", "TITLE_TWO")
    private lateinit var mDrawer: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var mNavigationView: NavigationView
    private lateinit var mDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    private lateinit var mActionBar: ActionBar
    private var mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mDrawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        mActionBar = supportActionBar!!

        for (i in 0..YOUR_VIEWS_COUNT) { tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitles[i])) }

        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

        mDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle)
        mDrawerToggle.syncState()

        mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view)
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)


        val pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        })

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            resolveUpButtonWithFragmentStack()
        } else {

        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.your_first_item_view -> {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(getCurrentFragment())
                        .add(R.id.content_frame, YourFragment(), Integer.toString(getFragmentCount()))
                        .addToBackStack("fragBack").commit()
                showUpButton(true)
                title = "YourFragment"
            }
        }
        mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            val backStackCount = getFragmentCount()
            if (backStackCount >= 1) {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
                if (backStackCount == 1) {
                    showUpButton(false)
                }
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showUpButton(show: Boolean) {
        if (show) {
            mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false
            mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            if (!mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered) {
                mDrawerToggle.toolbarNavigationClickListener = View.OnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
                mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = true
            }
        } else {
            mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
            mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
            mDrawerToggle.toolbarNavigationClickListener = null
            mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = false
        }
    }

    private fun resolveUpButtonWithFragmentStack() {
        showUpButton(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0)
    }

    fun getFragmentCount(): Int {
        return supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
    }

    fun getFragmentAt(index: Int): Fragment {
        return if (getFragmentCount() > 0)
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Integer.toString(index)) else NearbyPlaceTypesFragment()
    }

    fun getCurrentFragment(): Fragment {
        return getFragmentAt(getFragmentCount() - 1)
    }


    // Your adapter for ViewPager
    class ViewPagerAdapter(val fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    YourFragment()
                }
                else -> {
                    YourOtherFragment()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 2
        }
    }
}
```

I won't explain every step you'll need to build this code as the're a lot of tutos out there which explain the whole concept, but straightly encourage you to google it, to avoid some possible issues with fragment stack or standard android components in the future.